# PineScript: Exit only if profit 5% otherwise, hold

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Can someone tell me where is my mistake: I want to exit from strategy only if profit is 5%, otherwise long position should be open.

The issue right now, that `script` slices all open position if one of them shows 5%. I want to keep all positions open, if none of them reach 5%. (in option I put pyramiding 10)

Here is my `script`:

```
strategy(title="5% test", overlay=true)

// Chart Properties
testStartYear = input(2022, "Backtest Start Year")
testStartMonth = input(08, "Backtest Start Month")
testStartDay = input(1, "Backtest Start Day")
testPeriodStart = timestamp(testStartYear, testStartMonth, testStartDay, 0, 0)

testStopYear = input(2030, "Backtest Stop Year")
testStopMonth = input(12, "Backtest Stop Month")
testStopDay = input(30, "Backtest Stop Day")
testPeriodStop = timestamp(testStopYear, testStopMonth, testStopDay, 0, 0)

// A switch to control background coloring of the test period
testPeriodBackground = input(title="Color Background?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
testPeriodBackgroundColor = testPeriodBackground and time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? #6c6f6c : na
color.new(testPeriodBackgroundColor, transp=97)

// User provided values
smaLength = input(title="SMA Length", type=input.integer, defval=17) 
stdLength = input(title="StdDev Length", type=input.integer, defval=20)
ubOffset = input(title="Upper Band Offset", type=input.float, defval=2.0, step=0.5) 
lbOffset = input(title="Lower Band Offset", type=input.float, defval=2.0, step=0.5)
long_tp_inp = input(10, title='Long Take Profit %', step=0.1)/100

testPeriod() =>
    time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false

smaValue = sma(close, smaLength) // Middle band
stdDev = stdev(close, stdLength)
upperBand = smaValue + stdDev * ubOffset // Top band
lowerBand = smaValue - stdDev * lbOffset // Bottom band
long_take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp_inp)

// Plot bands to chart
plot(series=smaValue, title="SMA", color=color.blue)
plot(series=upperBand, title="UB", color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(series=lowerBand, title="LB", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(long_take_level, color=color.green)

longCondition = (crossover(close, lowerBand))
//closeLongCondition = (close >= upperBand)


if (longCondition and testPeriod())
    strategy.entry(id="CALL", long=true)

strategy.exit(id="Exit Long", limit=long_take_level, from_entry="CALL")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit different positions according to the profit of each position, you'll need to assign different `id` to each one. The flow should be:

1. Assign different `id` to each `strategy.entry()` order.
2. Calculate the profit or cost base of each `id`.
3. Use different `strategy.exit()` for each entry `id`.

You can change your code to:

```
if longCondition and testPeriod()
    strategy.entry(id='CALL ' + str.tostring(strategy.opentrades), direction=strategy.long)

for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    costBase = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i)
    strategy.exit("exit " + str.tostring(i), from_entry = "CALL " + str.tostring(i), limit = costBase * 1.05)
```

This will place a take profit at a price equal to 5% over the specific position and leave any position that haven't reached that profit target open.

Keep in mind that some of the functions I've used require version 5 of pine script. From your script, you only need to add `//@version=4` to the top of the script, and from there the auto convertor will do most of the heavy lifting. Here is the full code in v5:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='5% test', overlay=true, pyramiding = 10)

// Chart Properties
testStartYear = input(2022, 'Backtest Start Year')
testStartMonth = input(08, 'Backtest Start Month')
testStartDay = input(1, 'Backtest Start Day')
testPeriodStart = timestamp(testStartYear, testStartMonth, testStartDay, 0, 0)

testStopYear = input(2030, 'Backtest Stop Year')
testStopMonth = input(12, 'Backtest Stop Month')
testStopDay = input(30, 'Backtest Stop Day')
testPeriodStop = timestamp(testStopYear, testStopMonth, testStopDay, 0, 0)

// A switch to control background coloring of the test period
testPeriodBackground = input(title='Color Background?', defval=true)
testPeriodBackgroundColor = testPeriodBackground and time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? #6c6f6c : na
color.new(testPeriodBackgroundColor, transp=97)

// User provided values
smaLength = input(title='SMA Length', defval=17)
stdLength = input(title='StdDev Length', defval=20)
ubOffset = input.float(title='Upper Band Offset', defval=2.0, step=0.5)
lbOffset = input.float(title='Lower Band Offset', defval=2.0, step=0.5)
long_tp_inp = input.float(10, title='Long Take Profit %', step=0.1) / 100

testPeriod() =>
    time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false

smaValue = ta.sma(close, smaLength)  // Middle band
stdDev = ta.stdev(close, stdLength)
upperBand = smaValue + stdDev * ubOffset  // Top band
lowerBand = smaValue - stdDev * lbOffset  // Bottom band
long_take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp_inp)

// Plot bands to chart
plot(series=smaValue, title='SMA', color=color.new(color.blue, 0))
plot(series=upperBand, title='UB', color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=2)
plot(series=lowerBand, title='LB', color=color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth=2)
plot(long_take_level, color=color.new(color.green, 0))

longCondition = ta.crossover(close, lowerBand)
//closeLongCondition = (close >= upperBand)

if longCondition and testPeriod()
    strategy.entry(id='CALL ' + str.tostring(strategy.opentrades), direction=strategy.long)

for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    costBase = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i)
    strategy.exit("exit " + str.tostring(i), from_entry = "CALL " + str.tostring(i), limit = costBase * 1.05)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. It almost works as it should: seems that strategy closes from strategy.opentrades -1 direction, for some trades I see even losses, but with this strategy I should hold till I get 5%. As I see if strategy bought 4 orders and one of them get +5%, then all orders will be closed one by one, and this is how I get losses